# OpenCV Return value from mouse callback function

Tags: opencv

In OpenCV I want to return the point position like Point(x,y) to the main() function that I　click on the image in the mouse callback function . Is there anyway other than setting a global variable?

I don't want to write all the codes inside the on_mouse() function.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using global variables by passing a pointer to your data as a parameter to `setMouseCallback()`. Agree with @berek, just wanted to show a full example below to avoid confusion about global variables.

```
using namespace cv; 

void on_mouse( int e, int x, int y, int d, void *ptr )
{
    Point*p = (Point*)ptr;
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
}

in main() {
    Point p;
    namedWindow("window");
    Mat image = imread("someimage.jpg");
    imshow(image);


    //pass a pointer to `p` as parameter
    setMouseCallback("window",on_mouse, &p ); 

    // p will update with new mouse-click image coordinates 
    // whenever user clicks on the image window 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

to expand Safirs idea there, apart from a class or such, you could just pass in the point itself:

```
void on_mouse( int e, int x, int y, int d, void *ptr )
{
    Point*p = (Point*)ptr;
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
}

Point p;
namedWindow("win");
setMouseCallback("win",on_mouse, (void*)(&p) );

// changed value of p will be accessible here
```

Comment: I hate to raise the dead here, but can you tell me what the 4th parameter (int d) is? I can't seem to find a good explanation of the params for the mouse callbacks.

Comment: mouse state (e.g, when you move the mouse while one is pressed)

Answer (score -2):

No, this isn't possible, since the `on_mouse()` is a callback function. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#setmousecallback) is the opencv documentation of it.

So, "global" variables are the only way to solve this problem. Alternatively, if you're looking for a nicer solution, you can create a wrapper class in which you have the `namedWindow` and the `MouseCallback` and a private member variable, which is manipulated when mouse callback function is called.

Comment: Thanks. Then the only way is to set a global variable? Why OpenCV has this setting?

Comment: Yes. Or the wrapper class I suggested. opencv is mainly for image processing it doesn't have a reach GUI. It only supports simple user interface: [opencv documentation for user interface](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html).

Comment: I see. But wrapping a class for just a point position... Thanks anyway

Comment: This is not correct. You can return a value from on_mouse(). Just pass a pointer your data (`cv::Point` in this case) as the parameter to `on_mouse()`. No need for the wrapper class. See the answer by @berak.

Comment: Yes. However the `Point` still must be "global", in the scope of `main` function. For simple testing programmes, I'd go with @berak solution. However, if your application gets slightly bigger, I think it's better to create a wrapper class.

Comment: @Safir A global variable is the variable that's defined outside of the main function, global variables have program scope. I can declare my `Point` parameter locally when I want to define my mouse callback function. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/42-global-variables/

Comment: @Alex, I put the global between quotation marks and I explained what I mean, please read it again.

Comment: You can put as many quotation marks as you like, but it won't make the variable global. Pointer to my `cv::Point` object that I pass as a parameter to `setMouseCallback`, can be declared in the same scope where I call `setMouseCallback`. This would be the exact same scope if `setMouseCallback()` were to return the value.