# How to save mouse position in variable using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: function, python-2.7, opencv, return, mouseevent

I'm using Python and OpenCV for some vision application.
I need to save mouse position in variables and I don't know how.
I can get the current mouse position to print in window, but can't save it to variable.

My problem is similar to this one only I work in python: 
[OpenCV Return value from mouse callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570431/opencv-return-value-from-mouse-callback-function)

I define my function like this (for printing mouse position):

```
def mousePosition(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        print x,y
```

I use it in my program like this:

```
cv2.setMouseCallback('Drawing spline',mousePosition)
```

Comment: what is the problem? what is the output? what is your expectation ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Below is a small modified version of code from : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html#mouse-handling

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

ix,iy = -1,-1
# mouse callback function
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)
        ix,iy = x,y

# Create a black image, a window and bind the function to window
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('a'):
        print ix,iy
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It stores the mouse position in global variables `ix,iy`. Every time you double-click, it changes the value to new location. Press `a` to print the new value.

Comment: Thank you. Haven't thought of using global variables. I thought they shouldn't be used. Does it stand for Python too?

Comment: I use them whenever I absolutely need them. Never thought much about 'protocols' :)

Comment: If you want to avoid globals and you write functional style Python, you can use local ix and iy variables and capture them in draw_circle in a closure by making it a local function (Python uses pass-by-reference). If you use an object-oriented style, you you can encapsulate ix and iy in a class as members and make the draw_circle a method on an instance of that class.

Comment: @mjul : +1 - I think it would be really great if you could make this comment to an answer (with examples) and share it here (Personally me too like to see different approaches). Then people can select whatever approach they like. You can use the same example in my answer and show how it can be done without globals by the two methods you mentioned.

Comment: why the parameters in `def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):` are never used but the program works ?

Comment: The requested URL /trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_mouse_handling/py_mouse_handling.html was not found on this server.

Answer (score 13):

Avoid global variables by storing as class members:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np  



class CoordinateStore:
    def __init__(self):
        self.points = []

    def select_point(self,event,x,y,flags,param):
            if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
                cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,(255,0,0),-1)
                self.points.append((x,y))


#instantiate class
coordinateStore1 = CoordinateStore()


# Create a black image, a window and bind the function to window
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',coordinateStore1.select_point)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


print "Selected Coordinates: "
for i in coordinateStore1.points:
    print i
```

Comment: This is a really clever way to avoid globals, which *everyone* uses for these kinds of mouse callbacks in open cv.  I wonder what the downside of using objects versus globals are, specifically for this kind of use case, as you scale up to more complicated projects.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this Code:

```
def mousePosition(event,x,y,flags,param):

    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        print x,y
        param = (x,y)

cv2.setMouseCallback('Drawing spline',mousePosition,param)
```