# How can I avoid global variable with callback function

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I want to have the `label_image()` code into a function that is initialized with an image, *i.e.*, `label_image(image)`. Right now, if I do not declare the image as global variable, it does not properly update because of the callback function having `image` as global vs `label_image(image)` having a local copy of `image`. Also, despite the callback function `click()` being initialized inside `label_image()`, it cannot see the variable `image` unless it is declared globally. I guess my problem would be easily solved if I could pass `image` to `click()` which then would be able to update the same copy that `label_image(image)` received. So far, I didn't find anyway to do so as the callback function expects the 5 parameters `event, x, y, flags, param`...

```
def click(event, x, y, flags, param):
        global click_pts, image_storage, image
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            click_pts.append((x, y, 1))
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
            image_storage = lshift(image_storage, image)
            cv2.imshow("image", image_storage[-1])
            print('added %(n)s, size %(s)s, type %(t)s' % {'n': (x, y), 's': len(click_pts), 't': 1})
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
            click_pts.append((x, y, 2))
            cv2.circle(image, (x, y), 5, (0, 255, 255), -1)
            image_storage = lshift(image_storage, image)
            cv2.imshow("image", image_storage[-1])
            print('added %(n)s, size %(s)s, type %(t)s' % {'n': (x, y), 's': len(click_pts), 't': 2})


def label_image() -> list:
    global click_pts, image_storage, image
    click_pts = []
    image_storage = np.zeros((10,) + image.shape, np.uint8)
    image_storage[:] = np.ndarray.copy(image)
    cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow('image', 1400, 1400)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click)

    # Loop until 'q' is pressed
    while True:
        cv2.imshow("image", image_storage[-1])
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):
            break
        elif key == ord('b'):
            try:
                print('removed: %(n)s, size %(s)s' % {'n': click_pts[-1], 's': len(click_pts)})
                click_pts.pop()
            except IndexError:
                print('the array is empty')
            image_storage = rshift(image_storage)
            image = np.ndarray.copy(image_storage[-1])
            cv2.imshow("image", image_storage[-1])

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return click_pts

image = cv2.imread('someimage.png')
label_image()
```

Comment: not sure about python. In C++ you typically have one variable in the callback-header which can ge used to provide stuff during runtime. Should probably be the "param" variable?

Comment: in the setMouseCallback use the optional "param" variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Python function with partial parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258756/creating-python-function-with-partial-parameters)

Comment: @Micka do you have an example in C++ how it is implemented? I cannot find a single example in python.

Comment: @quamrana, I have no idea how this work in my context... I'm not very advanced in programming. I tried 'cv2.setMouseCallback("image", partial(click(), image))' with click(event, x, y, flags, image) to no avail. I really don't know what I'm doing at this point! I can't find anything how to implement the use of the 'param' argument.

Comment: try this cv2.setMouseCallback("image", click, image) then i think the image get passed to param .Have a look at this also https://answers.opencv.org/question/32888/passing-multiple-parameters-with-the-setmousecallback-function/

Comment: in C++ you would pass the address of image to setMouseCallback (maybe casted to void*) and in your actual callback function you would cast it to the image's class again. In your running code you would change image's content, but not its address.

Comment: @PrathameshJadhav Thanks!!! I'm passing the image_storage but it doesn't seem to pass by reference. Clicking (adding a circle) is displayed but adding a new one, the previous one disappear which suggests that the array is not actually updated.

Comment: have a look at the comments and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596511/how-to-save-mouse-position-in-variable-using-opencv-and-python

Comment: @Micka, thank you so much! Ahh I had this intuition but I was confused having the callback nested inside the class... quite straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to end up calling this:

```
def click(image, event, x, y, flags, param):
```

so that we are passing in `image` as the first parameter, we can make a `partial` function which has the `image` parameter on the front already, leaving the callback code to apply the normal `event, x, y, flags, param` params just as normal.

This means making a `partial` for the callback:

```
def label_image():
    # all the usual stuff elided ...

    partial_click = partial(click, image)  # here image is applied first
    cv2.setMouseCallback("image", partial_click)
```