# Opencv C++: Display pixel value using cursor of the image before applying colormap

Tags: c++, opencv, imshow, colormap

My apology for the confusing title. Basically I want to use mouse cursor to display the pixel value of image before applying the colormap. Is it possible? I know how to get the (x,y) coordinates from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570431/opencv-return-value-from-mouse-callback-function)
 Here is my code:

```
cv::Mat falseColorsMap;
void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* );
void showImage( cv::Mat frameMat){
    double min;
    double max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(frameMat, &min, &max);
    std::cout << min << "," << max << "\n";

    cv::Mat adjMap;
    frameMat.convertTo(adjMap,CV_8UC1, 255 / (max-min), -min); // expand your range to 0..255. Similar to histEq();
    applyColorMap(adjMap, falseColorsMap, cv::COLORMAP_JET);


    namedWindow( "Out", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );// Create a window for display.
    resizeWindow("Out", 800, 600);
    setMouseCallback( "Out", onMouse, 0 );
    cv::imshow("Out", falseColorsMap);
    waitKey(0);
}

// Function onMouse displays cursor values
void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
    if ( event != CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
        return;

    Point pt = Point(x,y);
    std::cout<<"("<<pt.x<<", "<<pt.y<<") ...... "<<(falseColorsMap.at<int>(y,x)) << '\n';
}
```

How to get pixel value of frameMat when using the mouse cursor? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the changes below to show original frames pixel values before color map conversions. Here color channel based condition is added. If it is three channel (BGR) image it will show 3 channels pixel value and if it is single channel image it will show the pixel value as well:

```
    cv::Mat falseColorsMap;
    cv::Mat framesMap;
    void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* );
    void showImage( cv::Mat frameMat){
        double min;
        double max;
        cv::minMaxLoc(frameMat, &min, &max);
        std::cout << min << "," << max << "\n";

        framesMap = frameMat.clone();
        cv::Mat adjMap;
        frameMat.convertTo(adjMap,CV_8UC1, 255 / (max-min), -min); // expand your range to 0..255. Similar to histEq();
        applyColorMap(adjMap, falseColorsMap, cv::COLORMAP_JET);


        namedWindow( "Out", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );// Create a window for display.
        resizeWindow("Out", 800, 600);
        setMouseCallback( "Out", onMouse, 0 );
        cv::imshow("Out", falseColorsMap);
        waitKey(0);
    }

    // Function onMouse displays cursor values
    void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
    {
        if ( event != CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
            return;

        Point pt = Point(x,y);

if(framesMap.channels()==3)
{
        std::cout<<"("<<pt.x<<", "<<pt.y<<") ...... [blue] "<<framesMap.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[0] << " [green] "<<framesMap.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1] << " [red] "<<framesMap.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2]<<'\n';
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"("<<pt.x<<", "<<pt.y<<") ......  "<<framesMap.at<uchar>(y,x) <<'\n';
}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much MD. Nazmul Kibria for your help. It solves my problem! Can you please explain how onMouse carries the matrix framesMap but not the framesMat itself? (if we omit the framesMap = frameMat.clone(); command).

Comment: Thanks. framesMap & frameMat both are same. But the difference is one is in global scope and other is in local scope. A global scope variable is known to other functions and that's why onMouse function can access it. Yes, you can omit clone command, in that case you have pass the framsMat as a parameter of onMouse function.